# Drawing Scribble shape in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Please look following pictures:
[image]
[image]

I draw a five-points star shape in scrribble.

My question is:

How can I do the same thing by VBA code.

Comment: Have you tried to register macro?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Perhaps Google "vba draw shape powerpoint"

Comment: *(My VTC was the wrong category because of [tag:vba] but stands anyway since I can't edit it.)*

Comment: PowerPoint doesn't have a macro recorder any longer, but Excel does, and luckily, produces a good start at this when you record a scribble shape.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg    Thank you,it can work.